# Does anyone know how to use titlecase in component.ts file instead in html file?

Tags: angular, typescript, title-case

I tried the following code but it's not working.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleCasePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'Working with Pipe';
  testValue = this.titleCasePipe.transform('firstletter should be upper case.');


  constructor(
    public titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe
  ){}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3kC2.png)

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add TitleCasePipe in the providers array of the metadata of your component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
providers: [TitleCasePipe]
})
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a7rj2x)

Comment: I get this error when opening the stackblitz example: Yikes! The page you requested couldn't be found.

Comment: @KevinOswaldo sorry, i updated the link. It works now

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I can see the example now

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an object, else, add in providers as @Gérôms say

```
  title = 'Working with Pipe';
  titleCasePipe=new TitleCasePipe()
  testValue = this.titleCasePipe.transform('firstletter should be upper case.');

  constructor(){
  }
```

Comment: it is injectable in Angular 9 : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i5bfaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is also correct, but I prefer to choose the first answer, anyways thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside constructor like this,

```
 testValue: string;


 constructor(
    public titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe
 ){
    this.testValue = this.titleCasePipe.transform('firstletter should be upper case.');
 }
```

Comment: the transform function returns the transformed parameter. So it will be useless to call the function if you don't initialize a local variable with it (and you don't need to put it inside the constructor as well)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code, anyways Why you need to have that code inside constructor or ngOnInit() is because is by that time TitleCasePipe is available to use

Comment: can you share your stackblitz link?

Comment: the proof you don't need to put in constructor or ngOnInit : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i5bfaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

## Without Pipe

---

Here is your Simple Solution with `TitleCase`

you can use directly like this you don't have to put extra code angular already give's this features

**HTML**

```
<p>
  {{name | titlecase}} <!-- this is titlecase by default -->
</p>
```

**TS**

```
name = 'Working with Pipe';
```

---

## With Pipe

you can check in `input` field also like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="name" 
[ngModel]="name | titleCase" 
(ngModelChange)="name=$event" 
#firstName="ngModel">
```

**TS**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'titleCase'})
export class TitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(input:string): string{
        console.log(input);
        if (!input) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return input.replace(/\b\w/g, first => first.toLocaleUpperCase()) 
        }
    } 
}
```

and don't forgot to add in `declaration` like this

```
declarations: [ TitleCasePipe ],
```

Here is my stackBlitz [you can check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pi3orz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)